# I want to shutdown the PC when it is in locked state

Tags: windows, python-2.7, datetime

I want to shutdown the PC when it is in locked state. I am using this code :

```
import datetime
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()

date = date_time.date()  # gives date
time = date_time.time()  # gives time

import os
while True:
        if time.hour==17 and time.minute==38:
                os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
        else:
                print "'"
```

I had locked PC at 17:36.
But its not working.what am i missing?

**Python 2.7**

**Windows 7**

Comment: Please verify the format of your questions look okay before submitting

Comment: Anyways, are you sure python is the best approach here? Windows Task Scheduler provides this feature already

Comment: Sorry for the format mistake, I am new here.I know, but I have a little different thing in mind. This is a trial patch code I am testing. Task scheduler does it at fixed time. I want to monitor the time as well as idle period after which I shall shut it down.

Comment: Okay, well in your loop, `time.hour` and `time.minute` are never updating. You need to find the current time each iteration of the loop

Comment: Thanks alot cricket_007 it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your never updated the time within the loop.

```
date = date_time.date()  # gives date
time = date_time.time()  # gives time

import os
while True:  # This loop is infinite
    # TODO: Get the current system time here
    if time.hour==17 and time.minute==38:
```

Note: Your `date` variable isn't needed